# Custom mini calendar for sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to set up mini calendar for SP 2010. I found [this](http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-create-really-small-sharepoint.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20SharepointBrandingDesign%20%28SharePoint%20Branding%20&%20Design%29) article but it does not work for SP2010. Maybe I've missed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used a open source web part for SharePoint 2010 mini calendar. See if this works for you.
Url: http://minicalendarwebpart.codeplex.com/